# How to use conditional operator with string concatination in java?

Tags: java, string

Consider an example:

```
if (sourceRule.getMaxOutput() <= 0 || targetRule.getMaxInput() <= 0)
    throw new Exception("Connection [ " + connectionType + " ] not possible between components [ "
        + (source instanceof Component) ? sourceCom.getType() : sourceMap.getType() + " ] and [ "
        + (target instanceof Component) ? targetCom.getType() : targetMap.getType() + " ]");
```

When I do this, I get cannot convert from String to boolean error. What is the solution for this?
Here `getType()` method returns a String.

Comment: what did you mean by string to boolean error? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't get any errors with this code (assuming a and b are integers).

Comment: And what are `a` and `b`? This code works for me.

Comment: Your problem is not in this line.

Comment: what is a and b ? check if you getting error in this line or somewhere else

Comment: My guess is that a and b are of non-primitive type and thus you can not compare them with `>`

Comment: On the simplified sample you had parenthesis around your ternary operator. This should work better once added to your new sample.

Comment: If you consider your question answered, then you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sourceRule.getMaxOutput() <= 0 || targetRule.getMaxInput() <= 0)
    throw new Exception("Connection [ " + connectionType + " ] not possible between components [ "
        + (source instanceof Component ? sourceCom.getType() : sourceMap.getType()) + " ] and [ "
        + (target instanceof Component ? targetCom.getType() : targetMap.getType()) + " ]");
```

Or, in short: put your shorthand if-else statement between brackets. Else everything before the `?` is considered the first part of the shorthand if-else statement.

Edit

For readeability's sake, I'd use the `String.format()` method:

```
if (sourceRule.getMaxOutput() <= 0 || targetRule.getMaxInput() <= 0)
    throw new Exception(String.format("Connection [ %s ] not possible between components [ %s ] and [ %s ]", 
            connectionType,
            source instanceof Component? sourceCom.getType() : sourceMap.getType(),
            target instanceof Component? targetCom.getType() : targetMap.getType()));
```

Comment: @SurajHK if you consider your question to be answered, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've wrapped your ternary operators incorrectly. Wrap the whole statement in parenthese, instead just the *condition* part:

```
if (sourceRule.getMaxOutput() <= 0 || targetRule.getMaxInput() <= 0)
    throw new Exception("Connection [ " + connectionType + " ] not possible between components [ "
        + (source instanceof Component? sourceCom.getType() : sourceMap.getType()) + " ] and [ "
        + (target instanceof Component? targetCom.getType() : targetMap.getType()) + " ]");
```

You could also use `String.format` to keep the String itself "clean":

```
if (sourceRule.getMaxOutput() <= 0 || targetRule.getMaxInput() <= 0)
  throw new Exception(String.format("Connection [ %s ] not possible between components [ %s ] and [ %s ]",
      connectionType,
      source instanceof Component ? sourceCom.getType() : sourceMap.getType(),
      target instanceof Component ? targetCom.getType() : targetMap.getType()));
```